# Trying to display the total amount of instances a value appears in a data set

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a database of football games with corresponding dates, locations, a home team, away team, and venue. The games table has keys that representing each of the aforementioned values. I'm currently trying to display each location with with its respective id along with the number of times that it appears throughout the games database as shown below. I coded it like this but for some reason its only displaying one venue and id with a count of the total number instances instead of each individual instance and I can't figure out why.
I'm new to MySQL so I apologize for any mistakes.

```html
SELECT id, venue, count(games.location_id) AS game_count
FROM locations
JOIN games
  ON locations.id=games.location_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to add group by as you'are using aggregate function

```
SELECT venue, count(games.location_id) AS game_count
FROM locations
JOIN games
  ON locations.id=games.location_id
group by venue
```